# Query Efficiency .contains

Tags: mysql, sql, linq

I would like to find the most efficient way to query the table below: Psuedo code is fine

```
City     Name    Comment               Mentioned

Tampa    Steve   "I don't like Jim"
Tampa    Jim     "Who is Steve"
Lincoln  Sarah   "Where is Angie"
Lincoln  Angie   "Hi Sarah"
```

I would like to find where people from a city mention someone else from the same city. There is a ton of data, so I need the most efficient way of doing it. I know how to write the query multiple ways, but I'm looking for the best way. So basically Steve "Mentioned" Jim, but if Steve mentioned Sarah it is irrelevant since they are not from the same city. I am looking for LINQ or SQL. 
**Note:** Jim could have 20 different comments, which is why I'm not sure if I should create a distinct list before doing the search for an author in the comments.
Thanks in advance

Comment: make sure you have a full text index on comment, and then use MATCH AGAINST

Comment: how do you know Jim is talking about the same Steve? He doesn't even know who he is.

Comment: The names are unique by city.

Comment: What a well-organized (and sedentary) society!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  t.Name, t1.Name Mentioned
from table t
inner join table t1 on t.City = t1.City
where t.Comment like '%' + t1.Name + '%'
```

Not a MySql user so I don't know whether this is valid for MySql, but it is for other DBs.

Added after discussion:

```
select t1.City, t1.Name, names.Name Mentions
from table t1
cross join
(
    select distinct x.Name, x.City
    from table x
) names
where names.Name <> t1.Name
and t1.Comment like '%' + names.Name + '%'
```

(This is SQL Server syntax. Adjust as required.)

Comment: Hi. Although this would probably work (somehow...) it is far from the most efficient solution.

Comment: True, but once you have it working if the performance is unacceptable you break out the query plans and go from there. I  can see an optimisation in getting a list of unique City/Name pairs and using that, but a) it obscures the technique he needs to use and b) increases the chance of typing a query that won't run.

Comment: @simonatrcl that's actually what I'm doing now "getting a list of unique City/Name pairs" and running a loop inside of a loop and I'm using LINQ to create the lists. I'm sure their is a faster way though.

Comment: Yep - loops will not be as fast as a SQL select. Amended answer above with a possible statement.